# Occasional "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship '...' between objects in different contexts"

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

We occasionally get crash reports from our users (we're using a crash reporter package that sends crashes to our server) with the following error:

"Illegal attempt to establish a relationship '...' between objects in different contexts"

(Different reports may have different relationship, it's not the same on all reports).

This seems easy enough, except that:

1. We only have ONE NSManagedObject in our code - the singleton from the App delegate.
2. We don't use any threads except for the main thread.
3. ALL objects are allocated using the context using `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` (none of them is allocated with a simple init].
4. The error NEVER happened in our testing (thousands of runs).

So basically we're stuck.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue in my app - one managedObjectContext, no issues in testing, crash reports from users with this message - I would really, really appreciate if you could tell me what you found out to solve this issue

Comment: Hi, any solution to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I'm working with Core Data in the main thread, I will put an NSAssert in any methods dealing with the context just to make extra sure I know everything is happening in the main thread.  Something like this:

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"This method is not in the main thread");
```

try using that just to double/triple/quadruple check that things are happening where you think they are.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, although as I said the crash never happened in our tests :(

Comment: more of a precaution than anything.  I had an core data based app that showed an MBProgressHUD while doing some work with the context.  Forgot that MBProgressHUD creates a separate thread, but never crashed during testing.  Only found out when it went live and a handful of users reported crashes.  So it can seem to work fine in testing while still working on separate threads.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I know that there are some operations that take place in a dedicated thread (although I believe that MBProgressHUD runs in the main thread because it updates the UI), but the thing is - they don't access Core Data in my App, so they're probably not the reason.

Comment: I was operating under that assumption with the hud, then discovered the showWhileExecuting: method for MBProgressHUD creates a new thread.   That's where my second thread was being created.